# Spring security custom authentication how to access firstname and lastname

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using custom authentication using credentials and ipaddress, however, I need to display user firstname and lastname on UI. Whereas I am not using UserDetails and I am using UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken, how can I get access to firstname and lastname, where UserDetails bean saved in Details.

```
Account account = (Account)accountDao.loadUserByUsername(username);
    if(!account.getPassword().equals(password)) {
        logger.debug("[USER AUTHENTICATION]Invalid Password:"+password);
        return null;
    }
    logger.warn(String.format("[USER AUTHENTICATION]%s %s",new Object[]{account.getFirstName(),account.getLastName()}));
    isAuthenticatedByIP = false;

    for(AllowedIPAddress allowedIpAddress:account.getAllowedIPs()){
        if(allowedIpAddress.getIpAddress().equals("0.0.0.0")||allowedIpAddress.getIpAddress().equals(userIPAddress)) {
            isAuthenticatedByIP = true;
            break;
        } 
    }


    // Authenticated, the user's IP address matches one in the database
    if (isAuthenticatedByIP)
    {

        logger.debug("[USER AUTHENTICATION]isAuthenticatedByIP is true, IP Addresses match");

UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken result = null;

result = new  UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(account.getUsername(), account.getPassword(), account.getAuthorities()) ;

result.setDetails(account);
return result
} else {
  logger.warn("[USER AUTHENTICATION]User IP not allowed "+userIPAddress);
}
```

how to get fields of account in jsp for displaying welcome message for user.

Comment: have you implemented `UserDetailsService` to get the `org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails` object

Comment: @SantoshJoshi I updated my code above, where the account is instance of UserDetails

Answer (score 0):

In spring mvc you can make a custom userDetail bean as session scoped bean and set your require values in it after successful login like firstname,lastname etc.Use that value wherever you want.

Comment: I am using Spring MVC with Spring Security

Comment: @user3364699 You can make a pojo class as per your requirement in session scope.See my answer already suggest you.Try first then tell if u have any issue with it.